# How to structure loops for gradient updates when data is not changing in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

The two code snippets show use of the same data to do n updates where one uses a persistent gradient tape and the other just calls it over and over again. The perf difference seems to be about 2x. Is there a better way to structure this going forward? I suppose moving data to device would matter on GPU?

```
@tf.function
def train_n_steps_same_data(tau, y, n=1):
    """
    In [218]: %timeit r = q.train_n_steps_same_data(q.tau, q.y, n=100)
    25.3 ms ± 926 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
    """
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        d = model([tau, y])
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(d['rho'])
    for i in range(n):
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        l = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    names = [x.name for x in gradients]
    g = dict(zip(names, gradients))
    reduced = dict()
    reduced['loss'] = loss
    return reduced, d, g

@tf.function
def train_n_steps_same_data2(tau, y, n=1):
    """
    In [220]: %timeit r = q.train_n_steps_same_data2(q.tau, q.y, n=100)
    41.6 ms ± 1.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
    """
    for i in range(n):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            d = model([tau, y])
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(d['rho'])
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        l = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    names = [x.name for x in gradients]
    g = dict(zip(names, gradients))
    reduced = dict()
    reduced['loss'] = loss
    return reduced, d, g
```

Answer (score 2):

The first approach is better for sure. You create a single tape object and reuse it inside a loop. The second function, instead, creates and destroys a tape object on every iteration.

However, you're missing a **very important** part in the first training loop: your tape is persistent. Therefore after you used it you have to manually delete it using `del tape`, otherwise, you're causing a memory leak.

Another suggestion is to do not use `range` when you decorate a function with `tf.function`, but to use instead `tf.range` (and in general, wherever possible, use the `tf.*` method equivalent for the Python construct, see [this article](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/05/10/dissecting-tf-function-part-3/))

Comment: I just noticed there is something missing in the update of the first one. I don't think the is being updated as the weights are updated.

Comment: Even replacing range with tf.range?

Comment: Yes, even with tf.range. I see different results when I do many steps.

Comment: I get the sense there is something I am misunderstanding with the behaviour of the persistent tape. tf.print shows that the gradient is not changing in that loop for some reason. One thing to note is the global scope of the "model" ... not sure yet if that is an issue in this persistent case.